# Spring multiple back up view resolver

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using weblogic portal with spring mvc 3, and have a requirement to have some backup jsp files in view resolver in case a jsp is not found then it should be tried from second path as demonstrated in following code:

```
<bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/path1/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/portlet/application/path2/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <property name="order" value="2" />
    </bean>
```

I read about adding `order` in view resolvers to do so but same is not working any suggestions on this please.

Comment: "But same is not working", Do you get any exception or what is the end result that you see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all [`InternalResourceViewResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/InternalResourceView.html) [should have largest order](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/UrlBasedViewResolver.html) (lower priority)

> When chaining `ViewResolvers`, a `UrlBasedViewResolver` will check whether the specified resource actually exists. However, with `InternalResourceView`, it is not generally possible to determine the existence of the target resource upfront. In such a scenario, a `UrlBasedViewResolver` will always return View for any given view name; as a consequence, it should be configured as the last `ViewResolver` in the chain.

But unfortunately these two resolvers cannot be chained since `InternalResourceViewResolver` extends `UrlBasedViewResolver` hence always resolves the view and is not possible to delegate to next `ViewResolver`.

Comment: any possible solution?

Comment: @Varun I think implementing your own `UrlBasedViewResolver` is a way to go

Comment: but i suppose view resolvers are singleton and cannot be updated on the fly, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Varun I mean that you can create your own implementation of `UrlBasedViewResolver` and use it in your context instead of two resolvers above.